# How To Get Directory In To Java App From Windows Right Click Context

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have successfully added a customized right click context in my windows. Whenever i click on it it launch my java app as i have already wrapped it in .exe.

I want to get the directory from windows right click context in  my java app and display it in a jTextField as it is clicked.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please clarify and please show your pertinent code.

Comment: i want to display directory in a jtextfield from windows right click context when it launches my java app

Comment: Depending on the context, it's likely been passed to your `main` method command line argument parameter

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer it was indeed passes in the main method i just got it out with `String incomming = Arrays.toString(args).replace("[", "");
                    String incommingF = incomming.replace("]", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer to my question with the snippet bellow in my main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
                String incomming = Arrays.toString(args).replace("[", "");
                String incommingF = incomming.replace("]", "");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incommingF) ;
    }
```

incomming is the directore passed into the application which contains the [ ]. thereby replacing it with empty text. IncommingF is the final directory passed into the java application from windows right click context

### Edit

After coming back to this answer a very important detail was missed, *args* is an array so I can get the folder by just simply accessing it by index

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
    String firstArg = args[0];
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstArg ) ;
}
```